# UML multiple ranges of values in MultiplicityElements

Tags: uml

In accordance with UML specification is it correct to specify multiple ranges of values in MultiplicityElements? For example, two ranges at the AssociationEnd: 3..7,10..20 or for an Attribute, eg. account:Account[0..5,8..10]. Popular tools allow to do that. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** No, this kind of multiplicity is not correct.

### Full answer

Sections 7.5.2 and  7.5.3.2 of UML 2.5 specification clearly defines that multiplicity is defined within MultiplicityElement as either a range between two numbers, a specific number (if `upper` and `lower` are equal) or a range from a number to infinity if `upper` number is `*`. Unfortunately you can not list just specific values. To be more specific it is listed by two numbers, `lower` and `upper` that define multiplicity range limitations.

I recall it was possible in some earlier version of UML, however I've seen it only in some book (that unfortunately I don't remember clearly), not the specification itself.

As for B.8.15.1 it tells nothing about possible values, especially doesn't suggest a possibility of listing several values/ranges.

So possible values are:

- `a`
- `a..b` (where `a` <= `b`, if `a` = `b` then it is equivalent to `a`)
- `*`
- `a..*` (if `a` = `0` then it is equivalent to `*`)

Both `a` and `b` can be expressions that evaluate to a natural number greater or equal to `0` if only the inequality of `a` <= `b` is held for all possible values of the expression(s).

Of course for in-line multiplicities they are put in square brackets.

On the other hand according to 9.4.2 StructuralFeatures and Parameters **are** MultiplicityElements so they have precisely one multiplicity.

Answer (score 2):

One `MultiplicityElement` can have only one [multiplicity range](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html#multiplicity-element).

Whether one `umlDiagramElement` can have more multiplicity elements associated is not clear to me. [Specification 2.5](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/) seems to allow it chapter `B.8.15.1`

Comment: On the other hand, the lower and upper bounds of the multiplicity of a MultiplicityElement are specified by ValueSpecifications (chapter 7.5.3.2). And they can have intervals, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Chapter 7.5.4.1 says "_<lower-bound> is a ValueSpecification of type **Integer** and <upper-bound> is a ValueSpecification of type
**UnlimitedNatural**_". So no intervals, just one interval _<lower-bound> ‘..’ <upper-bound>_

Answer (score 2):

Though the notation is syntactically not allowed, you well might want to specify sets. This can easily be done by attaching a constraint. If you're egg-headed enough you can construct a OCL script. But some clear text like `{ multiplicity  must be within range 0..5 and 8..10 }` will be fine. Just use a `*` for the real multiplicity.